# Integrating laravel project into magento

Tags: magento, laravel-5

I'm trying to use mage in magento project.So, i tried to install laravel project under magento root when .I open magento projet i have this error "Internal Server Error"?

Any idea is welcomed, Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

or use Magento over the api like this project, https://github.com/michaelkmartin/laravel-magento-integration

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understand why you want to do this, but you can't install laravel project under magento project. 
Magento uses ZendFramefork that have same functionality as laravel.

In case if you want use some laravel libraries you can try install these in lib folder under magento root. But you should understand you cant use laravel resources like  db connection and etc.

Comment: i'm developing my application with laravel 5.2 and i want to use some functions in mage.php "magento" i didn't know how to do that  ???